# Exporting maps to PNG and later changing map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, export, png

I exported maps to a png file but want to make some changes to the maps.

Is there a way to go back to the map you exported so you can edit it in ArcMap?

I really don't want to have to go through the creation process again just to make a small change.

Maybe some history tool exists?

Answer (score 2):

The only "way to go back to the map you exported" from is if you saved that map as an MXD.

Then the simplest way is to find it in Windows Explorer and double-click to open it in ArcMap.

For a very minor touch-up to a PNG you could pull it into an image editor like Paint.NET but I suspect that would rarely be viable.

Answer (score 1):

A `png` file ([Portable Network Graphics file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)) is an image file - a picture.  It has no reference back to where it came from, it doesn't know it was a map.  It could have been produced as a photo in a camera or as a graphic for use on a website.

The only way to edit the map is to re-open the actual map document `mxd` file in ArcMap, and make changes to that document and re-export.

If you haven't saved your `mxd` map document file, you will need to recreate your maps.